# Oracle queries finding gaps in dates, compare date ranges for gaps

Tags: sql, oracle

How to write queries to find the following data gaps.

--Scenario1 
-- Query1
--Find gap within same table (e.g. tableb )

```
ID      EFF_DT                                  TERM_DT 
800    6/15/2012 12:00:00.000 AM    10/14/2012 12:00:00.000 AM      -- GAP 
800    10/16/2012 12:00:00.000 AM    11/14/2012 12:00:00.000 AM
800    11/15/2012 12:00:00.000 AM    12/31/9999 12:00:00.000 AM
```

--Scenario2 
-- Query2
--Find mismatches between 2 tables (tablea  , tableb )

```
-- tablea  , sample data below 
ID      EFF_DT                                  TERM_DT 
400    6/15/2012 12:00:00.000 AM    10/14/2012 12:00:00.000 AM      
400    11/15/2012 12:00:00.000 AM    12/31/9999 12:00:00.000 AM

500    6/15/2012 12:00:00.000 AM    10/14/2012 12:00:00.000 AM      
500    10/15/2012 12:00:00.000 AM    11/14/2012 12:00:00.000 AM      
500    11/15/2012 12:00:00.000 AM    12/31/9999 12:00:00.000 AM

-- tableb, sample data below 
ID      EFF_DT                                  TERM_DT 
400    6/15/2012 12:00:00.000 AM    10/13/2012 12:00:00.000 AM      -- mismatch 
400    11/15/2012 12:00:00.000 AM    12/31/9999 12:00:00.000 AM

500    6/15/2012 12:00:00.000 AM    11/14/2012 12:00:00.000 AM      
500    11/15/2012 12:00:00.000 AM    12/31/9999 12:00:00.000 AM


-- Note 400 is a mismatch since ranges are different in both tables, 500 is okay (even though rows are split they still match )
-- Need to identify ID 400
```

The tables sometimes have 1/1/1753 for low date and 12/31/9999 for high date.

Tried the following query but it throws oracle errors for first scenario.
[ ORA-01841: (full) year must be between -4713 and +9999, and not be 0 ]

```
SELECT ID, TERM_DT AS gap_lower_bound, next_date AS gap_upper_bound
  FROM (SELECT t.*,
               LEAD (EFF_DT)
                  OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY EFF_DT)
                  next_date
          FROM TABLEB t)
 WHERE                                      -- trim(next_date) is not null and
      next_date > TERM_DT + 1
```

Thank you.

Comment: First, this appears to be two separate questions-- you should create a second question and remove the second question from here.  What is the data type of `EFF_DT` and `TERM_DT`?  The names imply that they are `DATE` columns.  But the data is not consistent with a `DATE`-- a `DATE` does not have fractional seconds.  Is it a `TIMESTAMP`?  A `VARCHAR2`?  Something else?

Comment: its timestamp field, used as date. thank you

Answer (score 2):

for Scenario1,, 
Lets take a sample,

```
    ID    EFF_DT         TERM_DT 
____________________________________
    800 15-JUN-12   14-OCT-12 --GAP
    800 16-OCT-12   14-NOV-12
    800 15-NOV-12   31-DEC-12
    800 01-JAN-13   01-FEB-13  --GAP
    800 03-FEB-13   01-MAR-13
```

the query could be

```
    SELECT term_dt
FROM
     (SELECT t.*,
          lead(eff_dt,1) OVER (ORDER BY eff_dt) AS next_date
     FROM lead_test t
     )
WHERE term_dt+1<>next_date;
```

which results:

```
 term_dt
__________
14-OCT-12
01-FEB-13
```

for scenario2:

As `select to_date('12/31/9999', 'mm/dd/yyyy')+1 from dual;` throws the same error.,

You're getting `ORA-01841` error due to the condition in where clause you've used in `TERM_DT + 1`, So better you should change/decrease the values those are in `12/31/9999`.,

Comment: will it work if we had a gap after `31-DEC-12` and `02-JAN-2013`?

Comment: As per the above query, it checks whether the very next day of TERM_DT and next row's EFF_DT are equal or not, if not, then the TERM_DT is taken as a GAP required for the OP. So it should work if there is a gap after 31-DEC-12 and/or 02-JAN-2013.